# DataGridView with comboBox does'nt fill with data

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have a DataGridView with 1 comboBox Column I filles with data. I asked before in MSDN forums but they are unable to help me because I am using [SQLITE](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/728eff1b-950f-4bb4-a154-430fb90f3c9f/populate-datagridview-with-a-combobox-with-selectable-items?forum=winforms).

It seens that the Column is NOT filled with data and I don't know why. The code I have is

if ((cmbCol.DataSource = myList()) == null)
                    return;

/********************************************/

```
    private List<string[]> myList()
    {
        string connectionString = dBFunctions.ConnectionStringSQLite;
        helper = new dBHelper(connectionString);
        if (helper.Load("SELECT Naam FROM Klant ORDER BY Naam", ""))
        {
            List<string[]> results = new List<string[]>();
            DataSet ds = helper.DataSet;
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            dataRow = helper.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];
            results =
            dt.Select()
                .Select(dataRow =>
                    dataRow.ItemArray
                        .Select(x => x.ToString())
                        .ToArray())
                .ToList();

            return results;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Properly i did changed the code:

```
            if ((cmbCol.DataSource = myList(1)) == null)
                return;

            cmbCol.Name = "Naam";
            cmbCol.DisplayMember = "";
            cmbCol.ValueMember = "Naam";

            dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(2, cmbCol); // there is no field with the name 'Naam'
        }
    }

    private List<string> myList(int col)
    {
        string connectionString = dBFunctions.ConnectionStringSQLite;
        helper = new dBHelper(connectionString);
        if (helper.Load("SELECT * FROM Klant ORDER BY Naam", ""))
        {
            List<string> results = new List<string>();
            DataSet ds = helper.DataSet;
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];

            dataRow = helper.DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0];

            foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                results.Add(row[col].ToString());
            }

            return results;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

but the combobox stil is empty, why? The data is in the datasource.